# How do I make git bash branching case sensitive?

Tags: git, git-bash

Let us say I have a branch named Dev. To checkout Dev I would type

```
git checkout Dev
```

Now sometimes, I’m stupid and type

```
git checkout dev
```

The system understands that I am trying to checkout the local Dev branch, so it refers to that branch and checkout Dev but with the name dev.

The problem comes in when I push this up to origin. It creates a new branch origin/dev when origin/Dev already exists.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Here's some [text](http://tosbourn.com/git-branches-seem-to-be-case-insensitive/), maybe it helps to understand the problem and the "solution".

Comment: Git's not built to defend against the confusion and ambiguiities and errors introduced by case-insensitive filesystems.  If you're stuck with one, you get to defend against that yourself.  Apple and then later on Microsoft did many thing right in re usabililty, but case-insensitive filenames were a botch from the start and never improved.  All the possible fixes to this problem (short of fixing the filesystem) that I've ever heard of are worse than the problem.

Comment: Thanks for this information, my team started with uppercase branches so I have to conform, they all use sourcetree so I might just end up using a gui to protect myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an alias that does this for you and then always use the alias. Note that you'd need to do it for more than just `git checkout`, but this is a start.

```
Jeremy@Jeremy-PC ~/repos/git-test master
$ git branch
  feature
* master

Jeremy@Jeremy-PC ~/repos/git-test master
$ git chkout Feature

Jeremy@Jeremy-PC ~/repos/git-test master
$ git branch
  feature
* master

Jeremy@Jeremy-PC ~/repos/git-test master
$ git chkout feature
Switched to branch 'feature'

Jeremy@Jeremy-PC ~/repos/git-test feature
$ git branch
* feature
  master
```

Here's the definition of `chkout` in my `~/.gitconfig`.

```
[alias]
  chkout = !sh -c 'git for-each-ref --shell | cut -f 2 | grep -q \"refs/heads/$1\" && git checkout $1' -
```

Comment: Hey thanks! Adding an alias can help me, but having to do it for every command seems like a pain, it definitely is great to learn other power user features. I'll definitely give this a go.

Comment: The other comments and answers are right--there aren't good solutions to this problem. @dlsso definitely has the right idea--never used capitalized branches.

Comment: I understand that, however I do not have a choice in this scenario. If I have enough influence someday, I would definitely try to change this. I just tested out your solution and it seems to help my a lot for now though.

Comment: I definitely feel your pain. There are times when you just can't control it and need to deal with it on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Never use upper case letters in branch names.

If it's not your project and you can't change the branch names you'll have to get by with what whoopata suggested.